# How do I get a contingency table from this data?

Tags: r, chi-squared, contingency

I am trying to make a contingency table from a set of data. So far it looks like this:

[image]

But I would like for it to look like this, but in R:

[image]

I've tried some things suggested online with other people's data, but it's hard for me to follow when all the variables and numbers are different.

I need to perform a chi-square test afterwards to test for independence between marijuana use and party participation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With `dplyr` you can do `spread(dataset, key = dance_party.., value = Count)`

Comment: Base R: `xtabs(Count ~ x + y, df1)` where `x` and `y` are the names of those columns.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = `Dance...Party.Participation`, values_from = Count)
```